# ROS Hydro on MINT 15, ROS_OS_OVERRIDE

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My name is Bolesław and I am new user of ROS.

I have installed ROS on MINT 15 system, all installing procedure went fine.
All packages installed correctly apart from ubs_cam lib! It throws:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
usb_cam: Unsupported OS [mint]
```

I have searched the net, ROS wiki and ROS answers. What I found is basically some old posts, which were not connected directly to any ROS release (quite confusing!), something about *rosdep.yaml* file as well.
And I found env ROS_OS_OVERRIDE. I put to terminal:

```
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:raring
```

When I check `rosdep resolve usb_cam`

```
ERROR: No definition of [usb_cam] for OS version []

No definition of [usb_cam] for OS version []
    rosdep key : usb_cam
    OS name    : ubuntu
    **OS version :** 
    Data: _is_ros: true
debian:
  apt:
    packages:
    - ros-hydro-usb-cam
osx:
  homebrew:
    packages:
    - ros/hydro/usb_cam
ubuntu:
  precise:
    apt:
      packages:
      - ros-hydro-usb-cam
  quantal:
    apt:
      packages:
      - ros-hydro-usb-cam
  raring:
    apt:
      packages:
      - ros-hydro-usb-cam
```

Here comes my question: how to "convince" ROS that beneath MINT there is UBUNTU Raring?

Or maybe there is workaround through OpenCv?

Thanks for any help You can provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99346/ros-hydro-on-mint-15,-ros_os_override/) by [merlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8611/merlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you tried to add  --os=ubuntu:raring flag to rosdep call?

something like:

rosdep resolve usb_cam --os=ubuntu:raring

---

Originally posted by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) with karma: 96 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [merlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8611/merlin/) on 2013-11-10**:
Cheers, it worked!